# How can I debug source jsx code in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, debugging, webstorm

I have React project. It's works fine, and program compiled successfully.
I want to use JavaScript debugger from WebStorm. All params you can see in the picture.

[image]

It's connecting to my app, but I do not see a source React JSX code. The IDE gives me compiled code like this:

```
var SelectedColor = function SelectedColor(props) {
  var style = {
    backgroundColor: props.color
  };
  return /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("div", {
    className: "color-selected",
    style: style
  });
};

var Color = function Color(props) {
  var style = {
    backgroundColor: props.color
  };
  return /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("div", {
    className: "color",
    style: style,
    onClick: props.handleClick
  });
};
```

I want to debug my code:

```
onst SelectedColor = (props) => {
  const style = {
    backgroundColor: props.color,
  };

  return <div className="color-selected" style={style} />;
};

const Color = (props) => {
  const style = {
    backgroundColor: props.color,
  };

  return <div className="color" style={style} onClick={props.handleClick} />;
};
```

I don't understand how to make WebStorm to show my real/source code in debugger. Any suggestions?

Comment: looks as if the source code can't be mapped to the one that is actually executed - sourcemaps are either not there or not accurate. Can you see your source code in Chrome Dev tools, for example?

Comment: Yea i included in my webpack.config.js file the same:

  module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
  devtool: "eval-source-map",
and clicking tab source in chrome  i can view and debug my code

Comment: `source-map` is better than `eval-source-map` (more accurate), but the latter should still work. Does debugging work for you now?